# Import external Js file in React as component

Tags: reactjs

I have a `.js` file which will create Gauge meter component when used in html. Now want to use that `.js` file in React component. So what will be the way to import this `.js` file and use as component as below.

Javascript file
    Gauge.js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use/include third party libraries in react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45658200/how-do-i-use-include-third-party-libraries-in-react)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

change your .js file to a react class component or functional component and then export the file to your react component.