# How to integrate web engage in React Frontend

Tags: reactjs, webengage

I got the source code for it but how can I import it and use it in my components?

```
<script id='_webengage_script_tag' type='text/javascript'>
        var webengage;!function(w,e,b,n,g){function o(e,t){e[t[t.length-1]]=function(){r.__queue.push([t.join("."),
        arguments])}}var i,s,r=w[b],z=" ",l="init options track screen onReady".split(z),a="feedback survey notification".split(z),c="options render clear abort".split(z),p="Open Close Submit Complete View Click".split(z),u="identify login logout setAttribute".split(z);if(!r||!r.__v){for(w[b]=r={__queue:[],__v:"6.0",user:{}},i=0;i < l.length;i++)o(r,[l[i]]);for(i=0;i < a.length;i++){for(r[a[i]]={},s=0;s < c.length;s++)o(r[a[i]],[a[i],c[s]]);for(s=0;s < p.length;s++)o(r[a[i]],[a[i],"on"+p[s]])}for(i=0;i < u.length;i++)o(r.user,["user",u[i]]);setTimeout(function(){var f=e.createElement("script"),d=e.getElementById("_webengage_script_tag");f.type="text/javascript",f.async=!0,f.src=("https:"==e.location.protocol?"https://widgets.in.webengage.com":"http://widgets.in.webengage.com")+"/js/webengage-min-v-6.0.js",d.parentNode.insertBefore(f,d)})}}(window,document,"webengage");webengage.init("your INIT key"); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You should create an account to begin with. You can start with a 14 day free [trial](https://dashboard.webengage.com/signup.html?action=viewRegister). This will enable you to get an account ID called licenseCode which needs to be used to initialise the Web SDK script mentioned in the question.
- Follow the [documentation](https://docs.webengage.com/docs/web-getting-started) to setup your account.
- For a ReactJS based frontend, you should add the SDK Integration script inside your `index.html` file and into the `head` section.

```html
<head>
  ..
  ..
  ..
  <script id="_webengage_script_tag" type="text/javascript">
    var webengage;
    ! function(w, e, b, n, g) {
      function o(e, t) {
        e[t[t.length - 1]] = function() {
          r.__queue.push([t.join("."), arguments])
        }
      }
      var i, s, r = w[b],
        z = " ",
        l = "init options track screen onReady".split(z),
        a = "feedback survey notification".split(z),
        c = "options render clear abort".split(z),
        p = "Open Close Submit Complete View Click".split(z),
        u = "identify login logout setAttribute".split(z);
      if (!r || !r.__v) {
        for (w[b] = r = {
            __queue: [],
            __v: "6.0",
            user: {}
          }, i = 0; i < l.length; i++) o(r, [l[i]]);
        for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
          for (r[a[i]] = {}, s = 0; s < c.length; s++) o(r[a[i]], [a[i], c[s]]);
          for (s = 0; s < p.length; s++) o(r[a[i]], [a[i], "on" + p[s]])
        }
        for (i = 0; i < u.length; i++) o(r.user, ["user", u[i]]);
        setTimeout(function() {
          var f = e.createElement("script"),
            d = e.getElementById("_webengage_script_tag");
          f.type = "text/javascript",
            f.async = !0,
            f.src = ("https:" == e.location.protocol ? "https://widgets.in.webengage.com" : "http://widgets.in.webengage.com") + "/js/webengage-min-v-6.0.js",
            d.parentNode.insertBefore(f, d);
        })
      }
    }(window, document, "webengage");

    webengage.init('YOUR_WEBENGAGE_LICENSE_CODE');
  </script>
  ..
  ..
  ..
</head>
```

- Now you can access the `webengage` object inside any of your components and further make use of the various SDK methods mentioned in the documentation.

```js
import React, {
  Component
} from "react";

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    webengage.track('CustomEvent', {
      'firstName': 'Alex'
    }); // version 1
    
    window.webengage.track('CustomEvent', {
      'firstName': 'Alex'
    }); // version 2
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <div className = "App" >
      <header className = "App-header" >
        <img src={logo} className = "App-logo" alt = "logo" />
        <a className = "App-link" href = "https://reactjs.org" target = "_blank" rel = "noopener noreferrer" >Learn React 
        </a> 
      </header> 
    </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <App/> , document.getElementById("root"));
```

- If you are using some syntax linter like (eslint) in your project, using the first version of code will throw errors. Please refer to this detailed [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45658201/7514459) for more on referencing unimported libraries.
- Thus, you can try using the second version with the `window` keyword.
- Further, if you are building a single page application, do checkout the [SPA](https://docs.webengage.com/docs/web-getting-started#for-spa-single-page-application-websites) version of the WebEngage's WebSDK.

Hope these steps help you integrate without hassle.